# ORA-00904 invalid identifier in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, ora-00904

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PURGE_PROGRAM
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE
   v_param          VARCHAR2(3500);
   v_sql            VARCHAR2(500);
   v_purge_count    NUMBER(17);

  BEGIN
    SELECT param INTO v_param FROM PARAMETERS WHERE NAME='rententionPeriod';
    dbms_output.put_line('Param: '||v_param);

   IF v_param IS NOT NULL THEN
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO  v_purge_count
      FROM
      (
         SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(UPDATE_DATE) > v_param
         UNION ALL
         SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(UPDATE_DATE) > v_param
      )x;

     v_sql := 'INSERT INTO tbl1_arc
               SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(UPDATE_DATE) > v_param';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;

     v_sql := 'INSERT INTO tbl2_arc
               SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(UPDATE_DATE) > v_param';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
   END IF;
  END;   
END PURGE_PROGRAM;
/
```

Above procedure, v_param is able to output with correct value, however subsequently I'm getting exception  `ORA-00904: "V_PARAM": invalid identifier` Perhaps v_param is not accessible from the String v_sql?

Comment: The code you've posted [doesn't throw that error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=15ca35c11f98ba52909facdea4344e09). Are you maybe trying to refer to `v_param` in whatever calls this; or after your (unnecessary) inner block in code you have omitted?

Comment: It must be the later code when i refer v_param in a SQL string that need to be executed,lets me update the question.

Comment: updated, the v_param need to be passed to v_sql for execution using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It must be the later code when i refer v_param in a SQL string that need to be execute

Yes. `v_param` is out of scope within the dynamic SQL you are executing.

You need to use a bind variable in your dynamic SQL, and pass the value in:

```
v_sql := 'INSERT INTO tbl1_arc
               SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) - TRUNC(UPDATE_DATE) > :v_param';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_param;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=065e1b910d5ac5bfd950e94e5cbe2d23)

---

Not directly relevant, but it would be better to avoid modifying the table column value before comparing it; so you could do:

```
WHERE UPDATE_DATE > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - v_param
```

or possibly depending on how you're treating the cut-off - so check which values are returned and which you actually want:

```
WHERE UPDATE_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1 - v_param
```

That would allow an index on `UPDATE_DATE` to be used, and involves less work overall even without an index.

Comment: Thanks, it returned which I actually want:
WHERE UPDATE_DATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE) -  v_param